# Disk encryption in linux

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

because of audit it is necessary to encrypt the data in the database (elasticsearch) I am an absolute noob in encryption after a little googling, I realized that there is encryption at the disk level (when you need to enter a master password or use the TPM module when loading the OS) and then ENTIRE disk is decrypted and second type of encryption exists at the file system level, this is when each file or partition encrypts / decrypts data on the fly

it is also recommended to use dm_crypt in conjunction with LUKS, but somewhere they write that LUKS uses dm_crypt under the hood and is intended only for encrypting the entire disk (that is, when the OS starts, all data is decrypted), and somewhere they write that LUKS is encryption at the block device level, and dm_crypt encrypts/decrypts files on the fly

I need both mechanisms or at least encryption at the FS level can i use LUKS for block level encryption ( after boot ) and file encryption on the fly using dm_crypt?

Answer (score 2):

> (when you need to enter a master password or use the TPM module when loading the OS) and then ENTIRE disk is decrypted

This is not really how it works.

Whole-disk (or -filesystem) encryption does not actually decrypt the entire disk at once: that could take hours on a large HDD. Instead, when you enter the passphrase for the encrypted disk device (say, `/dev/sda2` for example), the kernel sets up a second device, e.g.`/dev/mapper/crypt_sda2`. Through the second device, the contents of the first device can be accessed *as if* they were decrypted, as the kernel will intercept the input/output operations, and will decrypt all the reads and encrypt all the writes on the fly.

If someone hacks into the system while such an encrypted disk is mounted, the hacker will be able to access the disk just like a regular, non-encrypted disk. But if someone yanks the disk out of your system while it's running, and tries to read it, all that will be readable will be the bootloader, kernel, initramfs and the LUKS header of the `sda2` partition; everything else within the partition will be essentially indistinguishable from random data. If someone steals the computer while it's shut down, and tries to boot it, they will see `Please enter the passphrase for /dev/sda2:` and not much else.

`dm_crypt` is the kernel's disk encryption infrastructure, and LUKS is a header format for encrypted partitions or other disk volumes: they work well together. But the presence of a LUKS header will allow someone inspecting your computer to always see "there is an encrypted volume here". If that is not desirable, you might use `dm_crypt` in TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt-compatible mode instead, since that allows you to have a "deniable" encrypted partition, which can be accessed with two separate passphrases. One passphrase will reveal one set of contents (which you can set up as a harmless decoy) and nothing will indicate that there is anything else... but by using a different passphrase, you can unlock the same volume in a different way and reveal the true contents. Of course, if the "empty" space in the decoy mode is written 100% full, the "true" data will get overwritten.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but here, says that after boot all disk are unencrypted https://blog.hyland.com/it-security/showdown-full-disk-encryption-vs-file-encryption/#:~:text=While%20full%20disk%20encryption%20protects,the%20user%20against%20unauthorized%20access.

Comment: Think about it. A disk has a finite writing speed, that limits how fast it can accept new data, or have the existing data changed. It is impossible to completely rewrite the contents of an entire disk (or even a SSD of a significant size) in just a few seconds. The article you linked is written very cleverly, and has many true facts, but that one is false. Its purpose is, ultimately, to get customers to spend money to buy security services - and so this evangelist *stretches the truth* just a bit in just the right places to get the Good Word across better. But don't believe me. Check it!

Comment: okay, so what you think about this quote? This means that while the block device is offline, its whole content looks like a large blob of random data, with no way of determining what kind of filesystem and data it contains.  from here https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Data-at-rest_encryption#Block_device_encryption

Comment: That's correct (with the exceptions mentioned by telcoM), and telcoM hasn't said anything else. Everybody agrees that most of the disk content look like random data when it's offline.

Comment: To see that everything is not decrypted when the passphrase is provided, you can also think about what that would go. Most machines don't have enough RAM to hold everything that's on disk, so it would have to go to the disk, but that would mean *un*encrypted data hits the disk. As the disk can go offline quite suddenly, it must stay *un*encrypted on the disk, but that's not the case (and not what anybody wants).

Comment: okay, not the whole disk but for example if we load OS, all binaries and shared libraries which needs to start the OS and daemons has decrypt and load to RAM

Answer (score 0):

> while the block device is offline, its whole content looks like a large blob of random data

The data on disk ALWAYS looks like a large blob of random data.  There never is a time when plaintext data is written to the disk (if you're using full-disk encryption).  What happens is if you read sector N, the encrypted data is read from that sector, and decrypted into RAM.  Your app uses it in RAM.  If the app then does a write of sector N, the plaintext data in RAM is encrypted as part of the write to disk.